# how to remove same number in php?

Tags: php

I have done a lot of search. Almost every answer is about array. In my situation, I want to remove the same number.

```html
<?php
$term="1,2,3.4";
$n='2';
//I want to remove 2 when the $n equal one number of $term.
// echo out like 1,3,4

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(I assume that `1,2,3.4` the dot only was a typo)

```
<?php

    $term = "1,2,3,4";
    $n = "2";

    $arr = explode(",", $term);

    if(($key = array_search($n, $arr)) !== FALSE)
                                     //^^^ to make sure when '$n' is not found in the array, that it doesn't unset the first array element
        unset($arr[$key]);

    echo implode(",", $arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
1,3,4
```

Comment: Bravo...!! But a curious question: Why does it unset the first element when it does not find any matches...??

Comment: @tramp Because then you try to do this: `unset($arr[false]);` which the will be evaluated as: `unset($arr[0]);` Just remove the if condition and set n to 5 (And move the array search in the unset statement in the array index)

Comment: Oh yes... How could I forget that... 0 stands for the boolean false... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = "1,2,3,4";
$n = 2;
$term_array = explode(',', $term);
$n_key = array_search($n, $term_array);
if ($n_key !== false)
  unset($term_array[$n_key]);
$new_terms = implode(',', $term_array);
```

Ouput :

```
1,3,4
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not work, if `$n = 1`. In this case `$n_key` becomes 0 which is evaluated to false in the if-block. See answer of Rizier123.

Comment: @luator thanks for catching. I missed that. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have done a lot of search.

And you didn't find [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function?

```
$string = '1,2,3,4,5,6;'
$n = '2';

$string = str_replace($n, '', $string);
$string = str_replace(',,', ',', $string);
```

No need to waste memory with arrays or using regular expressions.

Comment: @Sabari 12 or 22 are numbers and OP says he wants to remove numbers. Not digits. Downvoting me because I do what OP wants, funny.

Comment: sorry I am wrong. I am not sure if the OP want to remove 2 from 32.

Comment: As you say OP wants to remove _numbers_, but your code actually removes _digits_.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = '2';
$str = '2,1,2,3,4,5,6,2';
$pattern = '/,2|,2,|2,/';
$after = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
echo $after
```

Ouput

1,3,4,5,6

mybe it's more simple