# In php how to assign specific array key to main array key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am getting this result after merge two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 36
            [banners] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 142606425210.jpg
                    [1] => 142606425209.jpg
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [banners] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 142606425209.jpg
                    [1] => 142606425311.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Now what If I want to assign `[id]` key to main array key like this way:

```
Array
(
    [36] => Array
        (
            [id] => 36
            [banners] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 142606425210.jpg
                    [1] => 142606425209.jpg
                )

        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [banners] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 142606425209.jpg
                    [1] => 142606425311.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Any Idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: why dont you just assign the id as the key when you construct the array in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will work,

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$value["id"]] = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

**Side Note:** I presume id here will be unique for each record.

Comment: When you answer questions where OP doesn't show his effort/attempts your are supporting this with answering it!

Comment: @Rizier123 - Like you help for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28969915/696364) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968462/php-strip-non-currency-characters-from-string/28968583#28968583) and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826304/how-to-remove-same-number-in-php/28826354#28826354).. :)

Comment: @Rikesh I see you put a lot of effort into this comment ^ (A good hour). But one thing tells me that you didn't read the question to my answers. Then every where you will see more or less a bit of effort research or some coding!

Comment: [Give me codez](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969663/what-is-the-best-way-to-random-1000-row-not-duplicate-row-from-mysql/28969915#comment46191131_28969663) consider as efforts?

Comment: @Rikesh If you want to discuss about such things, Okay: If you read the question you will see that he has a solution which works for him, but it's very slow, so he's stuck and don't know how to improve it. But he has a working solution which shows me that he did some work and now he needs help

Comment: @Rizier123 - No offence. All of us has same purpose is to share knowledge and to help others. So just end it here  :)